# Programmatically control Storyboard declared in XAML markup

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, animation

I have a Storyboard and animation declared as a resource in my XAML. I want to use a single button to start and pause the animation (toggle back and forth). When the button is clicked, how can I determine if the animation is running or paused so that I can choose whether to start it or pause it? The problem is, if the Storyboard has not yet been started, it is not controllable from code, and GetIsPaused() blows up.

Edit: I'm specifically looking to do this programmatically, without EventTriggers, so I can use it in a more complex scenario.

Comment: I never found a way. I ended up just toggling a boolean flag when the button's clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Use a toggle button istead, you can get rid of the flag since the toggle button has two states